# Git shared repository doesn't work as 'shared'

Tags: git, push, shared

First sorry but I did searched and found nothing that helps me.

I have created a git repository in the test server in my work, like this:

```
cd home/REPO
git init
```

then i cloned (empty) in my local machine:

```
cd /home/workingFolder
git clone ssh://me@ip:port/home/REPO
```

everything fine. 
then I copied some files (.doc) that already existed and then:

```
git add .
```

and commited and pushed to the server REPO

```
git commit
git push
```

My friend then, clones the REPO into his machine and GETS the files.

Now I included another file, git added, commited and pushed with no problems.

when my friend tries to pull or fetch doesn't happens anything.

Perhaps I didn't understood how Git suppose to work, but how can i share the files between my coworkers?
this is the config file in the REPO server

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
    logallrefupdates = true
    sharedRepository = true
 [push]
    default = current
```

Comment: Much more interesting is your .git/config. Can you post it? How did your colleague cloned the repo?

Comment: Did you add/modify the "bare" and "sharedRepository" values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I didn't understood how Git suppose to work...

That was the problem.

Solved the problem creating the central repository as --bare. The bare means that this repository does not hold any actual files of the project, only the information about the snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would just try and use github.  In that case I would do this:

```
$ mkdir my_git_test
$ cd my_git_test/
$ do the github stuff

Create the repository in github on the github site (free).
Then use the 'copy' link/button

Then, in a terminal do:
$ git clone [paste], e.g. git clone https://github.com/durrantm/my_git_test.git

$ cd my_git_test

$ touch aaa # as a test
(or move your existing files into the `my_git_test` directory)

$ git status # Make sure there are changes showing

$ git add .  # Add your changes to your repository.

$ git commit -m  "One Change"

$ git push origin master

Your friend can then do:
(github) Use the 'copy' link/button
Then, in a terminal locally, do
$ git clone [paste], e.g. git clone https://github.com/durrantm/my_git_test.git
```

Going forward, after making (local) changes you should follow the procedure of:

- Make changes locally.
- `git pull origin master` (see if anything has changed)
- resolve any conflicts (you will see appropriate messages if there are any).
- `git push origin master` (push your changes)

You can probably adapt this to work without github if you really have to.

Comment: github.com is great. But in work situations, you'll have to upgrade to a paid account if you want to keep your repository private. I would also check if it's okay to export proprietary code to third-party servers.  Some companies don't like that.

Comment: There was a problem with permissions. I changed the group of the REPO and works fine now. Thanks for the help anyway.